# Etwas »ist« oder »wurde« vorgesehen?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Which should be used in the sentence below: *ist* or *wurde*?

> Der nächstmögliche Zeitraum für die Umsetzung des neuen Konzeptes **ist** / **wurde** zwischen dem 01. April und dem 05. Mai vorgesehen.

Comment: Hello Emba Bakar, and welcome to German SE! Please take a look at our [help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help) to see what types of questions to ask and how to ask them. I took the liberty to rephrase your question a little, particularly the title, to make it more useful for others.

Comment: @Philipp OK - thank you for your efforts. I will check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken literally, the two sentences have slightly different meanings

> Der nächstmögliche Zeitraum ... **ist** zwischen ... vorgesehen. ==> the realization of the new concept will be carried out between ....

vs.

> Der nächstmögliche Zeitraum ... **wurde** zwischen ... vorgesehen. ==> the decision about when to realize the new concept was take between ..., but the realization itself can be at any time later in the future (we don't know when)

(although in everyday conversation, the second sentence would be understood in the sense of the first one too).

You can improve this by saying:

> Der nächstmögliche Zeitraum für die Umsetzung des neuen Konzeptes ist
>   zwischen 01. April und 05. Mai vorgesehen.

or better

> Als nächstmöglicher Zeitraum für die Umsetzung des neuen Konzeptes wurde der Zeitraum vom 01. April bis 05. Mai vorgesehen.

or simlply (my favorite)

> Die nächstmögliche Umsetzung des neuen Konzepts wurde für den Zeitraum vom 01. April bis 05. Mai vorgesehen.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you Stef - and yes, your favorite is my favorite too! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Keiner der beiden Sätze ist gutes Deutsch. Hier wurden zwei gängige Formulierungen vermischt:

> Der nächstmögliche Zeitraum für die Umsetzung des neuen Konzeptes ist (auch: liegt) zwischen dem 1. April und dem 5. Mai.
>
> Als nächstmöglicher Zeitraum für die Umsetzung des neuen Konzeptes ist die Zeit zwischen dem 1. April und dem 5. Mai vorgesehen.

Im zweiten Fall ist auch *wurde* möglich (Vorgangspassiv statt Zustandspassiv), was allerdings wenig üblich ist.

Answer (score 0):

Both is gramatically correct if you change your beginning part to:

> Der nächstmöglich**e** Zeitraum

Comment: Though not explicitly asked, could you elaborate on the differences between the words *ist* und *wurde* in the given context?